# Is it possible to make a rounded triangle with just CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to make the following shape with just CSS:

[image: Rounded Triange]

Here is what I currently have:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 56px 56px 0 0;
  border-color: #ff4369 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
```

I'm unable to use border radius to make the top-left corner rounded... Is there another way to do this or do I need to use an SVG?

Comment: semantically speaking, SVG is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To actually answer your question (and provide the first answer without `border-radius`): If you want a CSS only solution, you will have to use `border-radius`.

Nevertheless I would highly recommend to use SVG for creating shapes, as simple shapes like this are easy to create manually, it's responsive, it's [widely supported now](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) and (as @chharvey mentioned in the comments) semantically more appropriate.

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 50 50" height="56px">
  <path d="M1 50 V10 Q1 1 10 1 H50z" fill="#ff4369" />
</svg>
```

You can find more information about the path properties [in the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands).

Answer (score 11):

Yes it's possible using `border-radius`:

```css
.triangle {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: solid 30px rgb(200,30,50);
  border-left: solid 30px rgb(200,30,50);
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-right: solid 30px transparent;
  border-bottom: solid 30px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle triangle-0"></div>
```

Comment: I'll vote for this solution, this one has more support, but consider, this is not responsive.

Comment: @narek-t: responsive as in ?

Comment: responsive to block size. You're using fixed values (px)

Answer (score 5):

You might consider the `border-radius` and `clip-path: polygon()` solution:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background: #ff4369;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 100% 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

And another solution with the `:before` or `:after` *pseudo-element*, which can serve as a layer:

```css
.triangle {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background: #ff4369;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.triangle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: clip-path is not supported in IE and EDGE. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: no, i am just trying to give more insights in case someone notices.

Comment: I'll vote for this too, very clean way, and responsive.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily do with `linear-gradient` and it's well supported:

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.triangle {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ff4369 50%, transparent 0);
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle">
</div>
```

Comment: To avoid the the border-radius(op  says he was unable to use it) , you may combine radial and linear gradient ;)  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjgBQL

Comment: @G-Cyr yes I would do it like this also but the OP was unable to use border-radius with the code *he* made ;) he used the triangle trick with border so it's impossible to apply radius on it, but with my method we can easily do it :)